# Why my program keeps getting warning for "raycaster"? When I am not even using it

Tags: aframe

Why my code stops itself after half rotation during animation and I get the waring something related to 'raycaster'. Any idea how to fix it?
[image]
Could  anyone suggest the possible mistake  I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using a [cursor](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/cursor.html#sidebar). a-frame cursors use raycasting to check for intersections. The console warns you, that it would be more performant to [provide a list of objects you want to be interactable](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/cursor.html#configuring-the-cursor-through-the-raycaster-component).

You can whitelist objects by providing their selectors (for example by class):

```
raycaster="objects: .interactable"
```

---

For example here you can interact only with objects which class include `interactable`:

---

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse;" raycaster="objects: .interactable">
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" class="interactable"
    animation__on="property: scale; to: 1.2 1.2 1.2; dur: 200; easing: linear; 
    startEvents: mouseenter"
    animation__out="property: scale; to:  1 1 1; dur: 200; easing: linear;
    startEvents: mouseleave"
   color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
   
  <a-box position="1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0"
    animation__on="property: scale; to: 1.2 1.2 1.2; dur: 200; easing: linear; 
    startEvents: mouseenter"
    animation__out="property: scale; to:  1 1 1; dur: 200; easing: linear;
    startEvents: mouseleave"
   color="#AAFFaa"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```